# Can I use the word "it" in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

Can I replace the second "supply chain" with the word "it"? Will this change still retain the exact meaning?

"The supply chain associated with the semiconductor industry is dynamic which makes the supply chain complex."

Comment: The reference would be unclear. Personally, I would more naturally interpret a second *it* in that sentence to refer to the semiconductor industry if I were reading it quickly, not to the supply chain. (Because that would be the closest noun.)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, but you'd better make this clear:

> adding commas may help

like this:

> "The supply chain **,** associated with the semiconductor industry **,** is dynamic **,** which makes **it** complex."

(The third comma is for non-defining relative clause)

or this for simplicity (reduced relative clause):

> "Associated with the semiconductor industry **,** the supply chain is dynamic **,** which makes **it** complex."

Hope this helps!